# BibTeX: Harvard Referencing (agsm) missing "pp." after adding journal volume

Tags: bibtex

I wasn't able to google my problem so I decided to ask here. As the title mentioned, I'm using BibTeX with the `agsm` style for my references. However, after adding `volume = {22}, number = {6},` my "pp." is missing. As shown

> Diffie, W. and Hellman, M. E., 1976. ‘New directions in cryptography’, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 22(6), 644–654.
>
> Diffie, W. and Hellman, M. E., 1976. ‘New directions in cryptography’, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory pp. 644–654.

How do I get the "pp." back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change requires modifications to the `.bst` file you are using or a different style altogether.

Only one small change is needed to get the "pp." back, so we might as well modify a copy of the `.bst` file.

1. Locate `agsm.bst` on your machine. You can find the file path by typing `kpsewhich agsm.bst` into the terminal/command line. Failing that get the file from CTAN: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/agsm.bst
2. Copy the file to a place where LaTeX can find it (https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf) – the directory of your current document will do just fine – **and rename it**. Note that the licensing conditions of the file require you to distribute it under a different name if you modify it, so it is an extremely good idea to rename it immediately. It also helps to keep your output stable across different systems. Let's say the new name is **`agsm-pp.bst`**.
3. Go to `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}` and exchange the line reading

   ```
   { ",~" * pages n.dashify * }
   ```

   with

   ```
   { ",~" * format.pages * }
   ```
4. Ideally you place a short notice of the changes, your name and the date at the top of the file.
5. Save the modified and renamed file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{agsm-pp}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` in your document.

Alternatively you can get `agsm-pp` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/2986d9751f0d48377da6d44689713917, the link also contains a diff to the original, unmodified `agsm.bst`.

With the modified `agsm-pp.bst`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{harvard}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dh,
  author  = {Diffie, W. and Hellman, M. E.y},
  title   = {New Directions in Cryptography},
  year    = {1976},
  journal = {IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
  volume  = {22},
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {644-654},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{dh}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-pp}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Diffie, W. & Hellman, M. E. (1976), ‘New directions in cryptography’, *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory* **22**(6), pp. 644–654.]